# IE9 NOT getting 'children' of XML node

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, children

I have the following XML sitting in a var called RoomPriceInfo in javascript:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BkgItemHotelRoomPrices CurrCode="EUR">
  <RoomType Code="DB" Count="1" Desc="Double" Age="0">
    <PriceInfo EndDate="2011-12-17" AgentMarkup="0.0" MarkupPerc="0.1075" FitRdg="0.25"  MarkupPrice="48.73" AgentPrice="48.75" StartDate="2011-12-11" Nights="7" FitRdgPrice="48.75" CurrDec="2" CurrDecPrice="48.75" SuppPrice="44.0"/>
  </RoomType>
</BkgItemHotelRoomPrices>
```

and the following code:

```
DBRoomPrice = RoomPriceInfo.doXPath("//RoomType[@Code='DB']");
alert(DBRoomPrice[0].children.length);
```

Under FF7 on Ubuntu and FF8 on WinXP I get an alert of 1 which is correct.  However under IE8 on WinXP and IE9 on Windows 7 nothing happens.  It just dies silently.

Please can anyone shed any light on this?  If I do a `getElementById` on the DOM object and then ask for children on that, then IE8 & IE9 behave correctly.

Comment: Please don't sign your questions with your name, we can see it on your user badge at the bottom right. See the FAQ for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 15):

Internet Explorer (including version 11!) does not support the `.children` property om XML elements.

If you want to get the number of child elements, use [`element.childElementCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.childElementCount) (IE9+):

```js
element.children.length;   // Does not work in IE on XML elements
element.childElementCount; // Works in every browser
```

If you merely want to know whether an element has any children, you can also check whether [`element.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.firstElementChild) (or [`element.lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.lastElementChild)) is not null. This property is supported in IE9+:

```js
element.children.length === 0;      // All real browsers
element.firstElementChild !== null; // IE 9+
```

If you want to iterate through all child elements of the XML node, use `childNodes` and exclude the non-element nodes via their `nodeType`:

```js
for (var i = 0, len = element.childNodes.length; i < l; ++i) {
    var child = element.childNodes[i];
    if (child.nodeType !== 1/*Node.ELEMENT_NODE*/) continue;
    // Now, do whatever you want with the child element.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not solve the problem but.. you should use childNodes instead of children property to access the children nodes. I'm not sure which one is better, but I know for sure childNodes is wide supported.. may be Microsoft did it also like this?!

Comment: `childNodes` also include text nodes (not just elements), so that's not a good general solution.